# Joint Likelihood Function for Independent Exponentially Distributed Populations

Tags: statistics

We have random samples $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \exp(\theta)$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_m \sim \exp(\mu)$ where the $X$'s and $Y$'s are independent. I want to know their joint likelihood function $L(\theta,\mu\mid x,y)$, but I am not sure how to calculate it because the $X$ and $Y$ samples are of different sizes.

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to proceed in finding $L(\theta,\mu\mid x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just multiply their densities: $L=\theta^n\exp(-\theta(x_1+\dots +x_n) )\cdot \mu^m \exp(-\mu(y_1+\dots+y_m))$